# Fancyhdr header and footer disappear

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, article

Just as it says in the title, my header and footer randomly disappear after my second numbered page.

This is my preamble:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = hr_HR
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=none        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliografija.bib}
\nocite{*}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\ifx\l@croatian\@undefined
    \@nopatterns{Croatian}
    \adddialect\l@croatian0\fi

\captionscroatian

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sadržaj}

\title{MVC arhitektura unutar AngularJS razvojnog okvira}
\author{Marko Klobučar}
\date{Lipanj, 2017.}
```

The commands I issued to start the header and footer are as follow:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{Sveučilište Sjever - Multimedija, oblikovanje i primjena}
\rhead{Marko Klobučar}
\rfoot{Stranica \thepage~od~\pageref{lastpage}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

And all is well for a whole two pages. And then suddenly the header and footer vanish on my 6th actual, but 3rd numbered page.

I am terribly sorry if this has been answered before, I searched for an hour now and I couldn't find what I was looking for. I am also a complete beginner with Latex, and would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance! Please, let me know if I should include something I forgot.

**EDIT**: Here's the small-ish document.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = hr_HR
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[
% backend=bibtex
%]{biblatex}

% \addbibresource{bibliografija.bib}
% \nocite{*}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\ifx\l@croatian\@undefined
    \@nopatterns{Croatian}
    \adddialect\l@croatian0\fi

\captionscroatian

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sadržaj}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Now}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{Lorem ipsum.}
Lorem ipsum.

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{Header left}
\rhead{John Doe}
\rfoot{Page \thepage~of~\pageref{lastpage}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Sažetak}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{Uvod}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{Trouble!}
\subsection{This part is messed up.}
This section is where the header and footer disappear.

\subsection{Lorem ipsum.}
Lorem ipsum.

\end{spacing}
\newpage

\section{Popis literature}
\label{lastpage}
\vspace*{-1cm}
% \printbibliography[title=~]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Marko, try to compose small but complete document, which we can compile and show your problem. For text use text filler generated by package `lipsum`. From provided code snippets (at least to me) is not possible to say, what is going wrong in your document.

Comment: Okay, I added the short version of the document, only I removed the bibliography stuff so you can compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible simple codes:

- Either you use the `{spacing}{1.5}` environment, and you have to put the last `\newpage` command just before `\end{spacing}`, and repeat `\pagestyle{fancy}` right after,
- Or you use the `\onehalfspacing` command, and replace `\end{spacing}` with `\singlespacing`.

Here are the codes for the relevant part:

*With the environment:*

```
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{Predgovor}
Here's some text.

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Sažetak}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{Uvod}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{O tehnologiji}
\subsection{O pojmu arhitekture u softverskom razvoju}
Here's some text.

\subsection{Opis MVC arhitekture}
Here's some text.
\newpage
\end{spacing}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Popis literature}
\label{lastpage}
\vspace*{-1cm}
\printbibliography[title=Bib]
```

*With the commands:*

```
\onehalfspacing

\section*{Predgovor}
Here's some text.
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Sažetak}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{Uvod}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{O tehnologiji}
\subsection{O pojmu arhitekture u softverskom razvoju}
Here's some text.

\subsection{Opis MVC arhitekture}
Here's some text.

\newpage
\singlespacing

\section{Popis literature}
\label{lastpage}
\vspace*{-1cm}
\printbibliography[title=Bib]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works just dandy! I used the `\thispagestyle{empty}` version of your answer and now it works just as I'd wanted it to in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue. The problem was that The header and footer ended right after the spacing section ended, so I just did some manual wrapping and it works now. Here's the minimal code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = hr_HR
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 backend=bibtex
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliografija.bib}
\nocite{*}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\ifx\l@croatian\@undefined
    \@nopatterns{Croatian}
    \adddialect\l@croatian0\fi

\captionscroatian

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sadržaj}

\title{Here's some text.}
\author{Here's some text.}
\date{Lipanj, 2017.}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Here's some text.}
\rhead{Here's some text.}
\rfoot{Stranica \thepage~od~\pageref{lastpage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle

    \newpage

    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
\end{titlepage}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{Predgovor}
Here's some text.
\newpage
\end{spacing}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Sažetak}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{Uvod}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\section{O tehnologiji}
\subsection{O pojmu arhitekture u softverskom razvoju}
Here's some text.

\subsection{Opis MVC arhitekture}
Here's some text.
\end{spacing}

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Popis literature}
\label{lastpage}
\vspace*{-1cm}
\printbibliography[title=~]

\end{document}
```

It's not the prettiest thing but it does what I wanted and that's good enough for me.

Comment: You have no header-footer on page 6.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Now I see the problem. See, if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sadržaj}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{Now}

\fancyhf{}% head to be in preamble !
\lhead{Header left}
\rhead{John Doe}
\rfoot{Page \thepage~of~\pageref{lastpage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}% or empty)
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}% or empty)
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{Lorem ipsum.}
Lorem ipsum.

\newpage
\section{Sažetak}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\newpage

\newpage
\section{Uvod}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\newpage
\section{Trouble!}
\subsection{This part is messed up.}
This section is where the header and footer disappear.

\subsection{Lorem ipsum.}
Lorem ipsum.

\end{spacing}

\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty} % addin case if the Literature had not have fancypage style
\section{Popis literature}
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. If I understood correctly, I had to move the header formatting stuff into the preamble, and then just toggle the page styles where I needed them? If so, I have done exactly that but I'm still left with the same problem.

Comment: @MorinoAndo, do you test my MWE? do you extend it to more pages? it works in my place. if not in your, than you have something different from me, what, is difficult to guess ...

Comment: I have, it works. It also works if I move the `\pagestyle{fancy}` just after the title page, but the trouble is, I'd like the switch to the fancy layout to happen after the section titled "Sažetak", but if I place the switch after it, my previously mentioned problem occurs.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that your problem is solved. You had bearing mind, that effect of `\pagestyle{fancy}` come on the next page where it is inserted.

Comment: My problem isn't solved, but thank you for your input. I'll try to work something out myself.

Comment: What I want is very simple: In the sample document there's a section labeled "Sažetak". I want to apply `\pagestyle{fancy}` to **that** section and **ALL THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS**, i.e. the rest of the document. Everything before that NEEDS to be `\pagestyle{empty}`. I could not simplify this further, hope this helps.