# Fancyhdr - Footer missing

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

For anyone reading this: The footer was pushed off the page by the margin set by

```
\usepackage[margin=.7in]{geometry}
```

See comments below.

## The original question

As the title says, the footer is missing with the `fancyhdr` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% For testing
\usepackage{blindtext}

% General document formatting
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


% Colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{146,208,80}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%Header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{48pt}
\fancyhead[R]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colback=mycolor!100,
            colframe=white,
            arc=0pt,
            outer arc=0pt,
        ]
        \begin{flushright}
            \textsc{
                \textbf{
                    MyFancyHeader
                }
            }
        \end{flushright}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
% Footer - Why is the page number not showing
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
    % Title Page
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            frame code={},
            center title,
            left=0pt,
            right=0pt,
            top=50pt,
            bottom=0pt,
            colback=mycolor!100,
            colframe=white,
            width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
            enlarge left by=0mm,
            boxsep=5pt,
            arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
        ]
        \begin{flushright}
            \textsc{\Huge \textbf{My Title}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \Huge My Other Title \\
    %
    \large DEC \textit{Saarland} \verb|->| DED \textit{Sachsen} \normalsize\\
    \today
    
    % Page numbering should start here
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    \section{Foo}
    \blindtext{1}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Front Page] [image: First Page]

I have looked at this Q&A so far, but couldn't solve the issue: [Fancyhdr header and footer disappear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377585/fancyhdr-header-and-footer-disappear)

Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/4952336346rncwzqmcpmyd

Comment: Omit `margin=0.7in` to get bigger footer, then you can see your wanted page 1 etc.

Comment: ...or add `,bottom=1in` to enlarge the bottom margin, which will show the footer.

Comment: you are pushing it out of the page with your headheight setting. Better use geometry for all page related values.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments above. Indeed they solved the problem. Although now the title page in my non-mwe is a little messed up. But that’s for another day.